# Map function on spark dataframe row to parse a struct type

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a spark dataframe built using :

```
val empData = Seq(
  Row("1", "s1", Row("f1", "l1")),
  Row("2", "s2", Row("f2", "l2")),
  Row("3", "s3", null)
)
val empSchema = new StructType()
  .add("emp_id", StringType, true)
  .add("emp_state", StringType, true)
  .add("emp_name", new StructType()
    .add("firstname", StringType, true)
    .add("lastname", StringType, true),
    true)
val empDF = spark.createDataFrame(spark.sparkContext.parallelize(empData), empSchema)
```

I am trying to make each row in the dataframe getting replaced with emp_name's firstname(emp_name is of type struct). what's wrong with code below ? :

```
def mapDFRowsUsingRowOperator_getSeq_forStructType(df: DataFrame) = {
   df.map(r => { r.getAs[Row]("emp_name").getAs[String]("firstname") } )
 }
```

I am seeing error :

```
 Unable to find encoder for type org.apache.spark.sql.Row.
```

Also can we use getStruct() for this use case

Answer (score 0):

Change below function

```
def mapDFRowsUsingRowOperator_getSeq_forStructType(df: DataFrame) = {
   df.map(r => { r.getAs[Row]("emp_name").getAs[String]("firstname") } )
}
```

to

```
def mapDFRowsUsingRowOperator_getSeq_forStructType(df: DataFrame) = {   
   df
     .map(r => {
           if(r.getStruct(2) != null) 
              r.getStruct(2).getAs[String](0) 
           else 
              "" // You can change this null if you want to display null in column value.
        })
     .withColumnRenamed("value","firstname")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access the values of the nested column with a dot:

```scala
empDF.select("emp_id", "emp_state", "emp_name.firstname", "emp_name.lastname").show()
```

prints

```
+------+---------+---------+--------+
|emp_id|emp_state|firstname|lastname|
+------+---------+---------+--------+
|     1|       s1|       f1|      l1|
|     2|       s2|       f2|      l2|
|     3|       s3|     null|    null|
+------+---------+---------+--------+
```

This is an easier way to access the elements of a struct and requires less code. Furthermore you might gain a performance improvement as these kind of expressions can be parsed by the Catalyst optimizer while a map call is a "black box" for the optimizer.

More examples of these access methods can be found [here](https://docs.databricks.com/_static/notebooks/transform-complex-data-types-scala.html).